# unable to set public variable using a signal in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a few Qlineedits/QPushbuttons in a loop. If the text is changed, or a button pushed, I need to know a variable that I also create in that loop. I am new to c++ qt (have done a bit with pyqt in the past) and cannot work out how to do this.

I have thought that the best way was to create a public variable (`int workingID`) and use a lambda function with a signal. However, I keep getting a "no matching member function" error with the lambda.

```
for (int j =0; j<myTestNames.length(); j++){
    int currentID = j;
    QLineEdit *testTitle = new QLineEdit(TestNames[j]); 
    connect(testTitle , SIGNAL(editingFinished()) ,  [=]() { this->workingID = currentID ;} );
}
```

I can get the error to go away by using this format- but I cannot seem to pass a variable this way.

```
connect(testTitle , SIGNAL(editingFinished()) , this, SLOT(testTitleChanged(currentID)) );
```

I have tried so many variations of the lambda function, but cannot get it to work.

can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you declared a variable called "workingID" as a class member? If you want help, provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

> `connect(testTitle , SIGNAL(editingFinished()) ,  [=]() { this->workingID = currentID ;} );`
>
> ...
>
> I keep getting a "no matching member function" error with the lambda.

The error message is right: There is no matching version of `QObject::connect()` that takes both a `SIGNAL()` macro and a lambda.

You must choose one of the two syntaxes of `QObject::connect()`:

1. The old, string-based syntax: `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros, OR
2. The new, functor-based syntax: function pointers and lambdas

I recommend #2. See the [Differences between String-Based and Functor-Based Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html) article for a comparison of the two syntaxes.

### Correct code

```
connect(testTitle, &QLineEdit::editingFinished,  [=](){
    this->workingID = currentID;
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the link, makes a lot more sense now. Thank you